# Find the sequence with f(x)=$3x^{2x}$ as the exponential generating function.

Tags: generating-functions

I have to find the sequence generated when I use this function as exponential generating function:

f(x)=$3x^{2x}$

I don't know how to expand this function into a series.

Comment: First you have to shift $3 (x+1)^{2 (x+1)}$ then MacLaurin who doesn't give a nice answer 
$$\left(3,6,9,9,8,\frac{11}{2},\frac{37}{10},\frac{19}{10},\frac{118}{105},\frac{167}{420},\frac{47}{168}\ldots\right)$$

I can't find a closed form...

Comment: @Raffaele, Shifting $x \mapsto x+1$ gives you a generating function for a different sequence.

Comment: @MarcusM but $3x^{2x}$ has no MacLaurin expansion!

Comment: @Raffaele, Yeah, which suggests perhaps there's an issue with the problem.  

Kishan, where did this problem come from?

Comment: @MarcusM I found this problem while solving discrete mathematics by Kenneth Rosen. The answer given for the sequence is $3*2^n$. I suppose this is the solution for $3e^{2x}$ which means there is some printing mistake.

Comment: @KishanKumar, Yeah that's definitely a typo.  It should be $3e^{2x}$ for sure.